# Access list of delegate access persons in Outlook from C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to list all persons who has delegate access in Outlook 2013. I need it in an Outlook AddIn created in Visual Studio 2013. Is it possible to list these persons?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That is the answer...

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Can you explain how, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Namespace.AutodisoverXml` property - it will list the delegate mailboxes. You can see the autodiscover XML in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click the Namespace button, select the AutodisoverXml property.

```
           ...
           <AlternativeMailbox>
                <Type>Delegate</Type>
                <DisplayName>Test user</DisplayName>
                <SmtpAddress>user@domain.com</SmtpAddress>
                <OwnerSmtpAddress>user@domain.com</OwnerSmtpAddress>
            </AlternativeMailbox>
```

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can retrieve the delegate list as well as the back list (users who have the given user as a delegate):

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AddressEntry = Session.CurrentUser
  Debug.Print "-- Delegates (who can send of behalf of "  & AddressEntry.Name & ")"
  for each AE in AddressEntry.Delegates
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "-- Is delegate for (can send on behalf of these users)"
  for each AE in AddressEntry.IsDelegateFor
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "-- Is member of the following Dist Lists:"
  for each AE in AddressEntry.IsMemberOfDL
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "-- The following users report to " & AddressEntry.Name
  for each AE in AddressEntry.Reports
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
```